# How to extract numbers?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have a database like that:

```
stockCode stockName stockStart stockFinish stockCurrentNumber
__________________________________________________________
100       Water         1          10          ?
```

Now how do I code it so that it looks like this...

```
stockCode stockName stockStart stockFinish stockCurrentNumber
__________________________________________________________
100001       Water         1          10          001

100002       Water         1          10          002

100003       Water         1          10          003

100004       Water         1          10          004

100005       Water         1          10          005

100006       Water         1          10          006

100007       Water         1          10          007

100008       Water         1          10          008

100009       Water         1          10          009

100010       Water         1          10          010
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help

SORRY, EDIT, I ONLY HAVE ONE RECORD, AND WANT IT TO BE DUPLICATED IN THE RANGE stockStart to stockFinish

Comment: what is the datatype of the 1st and last column?

Comment: @BhupeshC they are both `SMALLINT`. How do I extract all the numbers from stockStart to stockFinish and insert them into stockCurrentNumber??

Comment: if the last column is SMALLINT, how does it show preceding 0s?

Comment: paste the table DDL please

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT   
CONCAT(`stockCode`,lpad(@sno + 1,3,0)) stockCode,
`stockName`, 
`stockStart`,
`stockFinish`,
@sno := lpad(@sno + 1,3,0) AS stockCurrentNumbe
FROM  Table1,
(SELECT @sno := 000) t
```

### [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/660b0/5)

**Edit**

For update you can create new table (for reference [*see fiddle demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29894/4)) using the below query and once done you can rename your table to the actual table and for below example i have use `int()` not smallint

```
CREATE TABLE Table2
    (`stockCode` int(11),
     `stockName` varchar(5),
     `stockStart` int,
     `stockFinish` int, 
     `stockCurrentNumber` int(11))
;
INSERT INTO Table2
    (`stockCode`, 
     `stockName`, 
     `stockStart`,
     `stockFinish`, 
     `stockCurrentNumber`)

SELECT   
CONCAT(`stockCode`,lpad(@sno + 1,3,'0')) stockCode, 
  `stockName`, 
  `stockStart`,
  `stockFinish`,
  @sno := lpad(@sno + 1,3,'0') AS stockCurrentNumber
FROM  Table1,
(SELECT @sno := 000) t
;
```

The data in column `stockCurrentNumber` of table2 will have the data without leading zeros because the datatype is integer and 001 =1 so for the leading zeros where you fetch the results you can use `lpad(stockCurrentNumber,3,'0')` for more see [*LPAD Docs*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) and for the query its not harder one i have just used the variable to generate auto incremented values for your  `stockCurrentNumber` column and [*CONCAT()*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)  to combine to values like auto incremented value and the `stockCode` as `CONCAT(`stockCode`,lpad(@sno + 1,3,'0')) stockCode`,Hope it makes sense

### [Fiddle 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29894/4)

Comment: Hi, Could you please explain this code to me. Also, how do I do it as an update statement? I tried 
`INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (
CONCAT(`stockCode`,lpad(@sno + 1,3,0)) stockCode,
`stockName`, 
`stockStart`,
`stockFinish`,
@sno := lpad(@sno + 1,3,0) AS stockCurrentNumbe`)`

BUT I keep getting this error ` You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'stockCode, `stockName`, `stockStart`, `stockFinish`, @sno := lpad(@sno + 1,3,0)' at line 2:`

Comment: Sorry, could you please help me modify your code such that it works on my updated database that I am currently testing please

Comment: @user3138212 You could just Select ........ INTO <table you want to insert> FROM ....

Or do a nested Insert Into table2 SELECT ...............

Comment: @user3138212 see my updated answer and [*updated fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29894/4)